# When diameter of a set is equal to Lebesgue measure of that set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, real-numbers

Let's take the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Now consider a set $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ which has Lebesgue measure non zero i.e. $\lambda(E)\ne 0$. Is there a subset $A$ of $E$ such that $\operatorname{diam}(A) = \lambda(A)$ where $\operatorname{diam}(A)=\sup A - \inf A$?
**Note that $\lambda(A)$ should be non-zero.**

Comment: I expect the answer to be: *no*, if $E$ is hollow. In any case, you should provide more context and working

Comment: What about an interval?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur I am saying for any such E is it possible..

Comment: @FShrike I am asking for a subset for any such non zero measurable set.

Comment: Yes. Just take $A$ with one element.

Comment: @jjagmath oh yeah sorry for that . Actually I want a subset of nonzero measure. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not always possible.

Let $E\subset[0,1]$ be a fat Cantor set. As a Cantor set, $E$ has the property that any nonempty open set $U\subset\mathbb R$ has an interval $V\subset U$ such that $V\cap E=\emptyset$.

Consider any measurable $A\subset E$ with $\lambda(A)>0$. Let $a=\text{diam}\, A$. Since $A$ has positive measure, $a>0$ so there is some $b\geq0$ such that $A\subset [b,b+a]\cap E$. Thus, there is an interval $V\subset (b,b+a)$ such that $V\cap E=V\cap A=\emptyset$. Thus, $\lambda(A)\leq\lambda([b,b+a]\setminus V)=\lambda([b,b+a])-\lambda(V)=a-\lambda(V)<a$.